# Как реализовать кольцевой список в python?

Tags: python, список, числа

Как высчитать расстояние между элементами в списке, будто он представлен в виде кольца.

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(arr.index(9) - arr.index(2))
print(arr.index(0) - arr.index(7))
```

[image: Список в виде кольца]

Comment: `dist = min(abs(index1 - index2), n - abs(index1 - index2))`

Comment: Красивое решение. Если что, `n` - это длинна массива (`len(arr)`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093638/7023590